# Submitting multiple forms with jQuery Form Plugin to same server-side script

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an application where I want to submit multiple forms using a single submit button. The forms may contain images to be uploaded, therefore, I have been looking at using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form).

Each form needs to be sent to the same server-side script for processing, however, using the code below, I can see that the server-side script is called twice but the same form data is supplied from the last form submitted rather than data from each form.

Here is the `html`

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" name="product_name" /><br />
    <select name="product_category">
        <option value="Long sleeved">Long Sleeved</option>
        <option value="Short Sleeved">Short Sleeved</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" /><br /><br />
</form>

<form id="form2"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" name="product_name" /><br />
    <select name="product_category">
        <option value="Long sleeved">Long Sleeved</option>
        <option value="Short Sleeved">Short Sleeved</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" /><br /><br />
</form>

<a href="#" id="myButton">Submit</a>
```

and the Javasript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = {
            url: 'comment.php'
        }

    $('form').each(function(){
        $(this).ajaxForm(function() { 
            // optionally do stuff here after forms submitted
        });
    });

    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        $('form').each(function(){
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A file upload is not possible through ajax, if you want to do some interactive uploading you either have to use HTML5 or create the forms in different iframes.

Comment: I'm using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) which handles file uploads. That aside, it doesn't address whether 2 forms can be submitted using this plugin.

Comment: even jQuery Form Plugin won't handle your file uploads via Ajax. Which then in that case addresses your problem, as this is the only difference in the two forms i can see.

Comment: I see. So even though I can use the above code for one form which seems to be successful, I can't for multiple forms?

Comment: Right, data has to be reloaded when you submit files, and data in the second form will therefor be removed